# Login system in PHP using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, sql, oauth

I am beginning the cycle of creating my role based access control into my framework. I now want to log the user into my application and my _user table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `_users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `hash` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `session` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

I create my user like so in my model, where `bin2hex()` is my IV / salt.

```
Database::getInstance()->Prepare( 'INSERT INTO _users (username, hash, session) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' )
                       ->execute( array(
                           'Test',
                           password_hash( 'Test', PASSWORD_BCRYPT ),
                           md5( time() . bin2hex( random_bytes( 32 ) ) )
                       ) );
```

To then log into the user, I use a method. The method I use in the request is `POST` because my application has built in CRSF tokens. If the CRSF token is passed, then a `xauth_protected` aliased class is instanced which ensures that `X-Auth` header exists and is of `md5(session_id())` to ensure that no cross-site-origin requests can be made.

```
public function login( Request $request )
{
    $this->middleware( 'json_response', $request );
    $this->middleware( 'xauth_protected', $request );
    
    if( !$request->has( 'username' ) || !$request->has( 'password') )
    {
        echo json_encode( array( 
            'status' => FALSE,
            'reason' => 'Please fill in the required fields...',
        ) );
        return;
    }
    
    $stmt = Database::getInstance()->Prepare( 'SELECT id, hash, session FROM _users WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1' );
    $stmt->execute( array( $request->username ) );
    $row  = (object) $stmt->fetch();
    
    if( isset( $row->id ) )
    {
        if( password_verify( $request->password, $row->hash ) )
        {
            // $_SESSION['oath'] = $row->session
            // This is used to find the user that is logged in, if it is set
            $request->setSession( 'oauth', $row->session );
            
            echo json_encode( array( 
                'status' => TRUE,
            ) );
            
            return;
        }
        
        echo json_encode( array( 
            'status' => FALSE,
            'reason' => 'Invalid credentials...',
        ) );
        
        return;
    }
    
    echo json_encode( array( 
            'status' => FALSE,
            'reason' => 'Sorry, that username was not found in our records...',
        ) );
}
```

To then test this method, I can use:

```
const formData = new FormData();
    
formData.append( 'crsf_token', sessionStorage.getItem( 'token' ) ); // CRSF token is set elsewhere
formData.append( 'username', document.getElementById( 'username' ).value ); // Example input field
formData.append( 'password', document.getElementById( 'password' ).value ); // Example input field

fetch( App.__viewFactory.homepage.login, { // This is a prestored route that looks like /oauth/login
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'X-Auth': sessionStorage.getItem( 'session' ) // md5( session_id() ) which is set elsewhere
    },
    body: formData
} )
.then( response => response.json() )
.then( data     => {
    if( data.result ) {
        window.location.href = App.__viewFactory.dashboard.view; // prestored route to the dashboard
        return;
    }
        
    document.getElementById( 'login-error' ).innerHTML = data.reason;
} )
.catch(error => {
    document.getElementById( 'login-error' ).innerHTML = 'Oh no! Something went wrong.';
});
```

I have incorporated CRSF protected, custom headers using the `session_id()` to prevent cross-origin requests (since my framework rewrites all requests to my index page, this then turns on CORS). Is everything I am doing on the database side as secure? Is there something I could be doing better?

Comment: "Is everything I am doing on the database side as secure?" Secure against what/who?

Comment: what is session?

Comment: session is just the output of `md5(session_id())` - it probably has absolutely no adversary effect but deception is a key defence principle even if so. These are set on a `.tpl` file which my page executes. I can show that if needed @YourCommonSense

Comment: I am sorry, what?

Comment: I appreciate you want me to expand on 'secure' but I am trying to generalise the noun. Am I doing everything correctly is what I am trying to ask, what is best practice, am I generating my sessions correctly etc etc @Mast

Comment: The column `session` in my `_user` table is for storing a string that is then stored in a `$_SESSION` when the user successfully logs in. This way, in my PHP logic, if the `$_SESSION['oauth']` `isset()` then I can query the table using the session.

The `sessionStorage` item key `session` is just a PHP outputted `md5(session_id())`. The idea here was because my `.htaccess` rewrites all requests to my `index.php`, I wanted to stop cross-origin requests, I hope this clears anything up @YourCommonSense

Comment: I don't really get the meaning. Is it a csrf token? If so, why don't you store it in a session?

Comment: Its a way of the referrer authorising itself. If the referrer does not know the `md5(session_id())` value, then clearly it did not come from the same origin. Does that make more sense or is this needless? I'm new to CORS and don't fully yet understand it. I [created a gist](https://gist.github.com/Jaquarh/b5292dc7540765f58a0ddd27c7e0425e#file-app-tpl-L60) if you want to see where it gets set and how it gets set. @YourCommonSense

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111130/discussion-between-jaquarh-and-your-common-sense).

Comment: Where is `data.result` coming from?  I see that you are passing and receiving `data.reason` and I see you are passing and ignoring `data.status`.

Comment: That is a complete typo and I am glad you saw that because that would of been a nightmare trying to figure out why it wasn't redirecting correctly on a correct login attempt! It should be `if( data.status )`. Thanks @mickmackusa

Comment: I have altered the title, thanks @mickmackusa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your querying practices look secure to me.  Your are using a prepared statement with bound parameters and using `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`.  It really can be as simple as doing those basic/essential things.

As for other refinements, I recommend writing the failure branches before successful ones, doing early `exit()`s, and only passing back an empty or populated `reason` to reduce the data structure to its vital value.

- I will assume/hope that the `username` is a UNIQUE table column, so `LIMIT 1` provides no value.
- If you want the result set / row to be an object, just tell pdo that that is what you want -- `fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)`.
- The result set will either be an object or `false`, so just check for a falsey result set.  For this reason, you can remove `id` from the `SELECT`.
- I don't like to give too much specificity when giving failed login responses.  I would tell the user that the credentials generally failed without spelling out which field was the problem.

Recommendation:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->middleware('json_response', $request);
    $this->middleware('xauth_protected', $request);
    
    if(!$request->has('username') || !$request->has('password')) {
        exit(json_encode(['reason' => 'Please fill in the required fields']);
    }
    
    $stmt = Database::getInstance()->Prepare(
        "SELECT hash, session FROM _users WHERE username = ?"
    );
    $stmt->execute([$request->username]);
    $rowObject = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    
    if (!$rowObject || !password_verify($request->password, $rowObject->hash)) {
        exit(json_encode(['reason' => 'Invalid credentials']));
    }

    $request->setSession('oauth', $rowObject->session);
    exit(json_encode(['reason' => null]));
}
```

Then in your js, you can use this:

```
.then(data => {
    if (data.reason) {
        document.getElementById('login-error').innerHTML = data.reason;
    } else {
        window.location.href = App.__viewFactory.dashboard.view;
    }
})
```

Comment: It is nice to see that, even though there may be no direct server security issues, that the thought of brute forcing ties in with the ability of giving the user a specific output rather than generalising it. I think I should perhaps integrate an "attempts" into it also. I appreciate your time in writing this, its nice to know I can use `fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)` without having to cast the array to an object. The reason I do not use `exit()` is because the middleware in my script runs functions after the route has executed which could be things like re-generating  the CRSF token for POST requests

Comment: It would be nice to add you as a collaborator to see your opinion of the framework so far

Comment: Sorry, but due to my 9 to 5 dev job that is rarely only 9 to 5, my Stack Exchange addiction (can't argue that it is anything other than an addiction because my wife is a neuroscientist and mental wellness professional), my family, and what is left of my sleep schedule -- there isn't much left over to devote to new endeavours.

Comment: The drawback of using an attempts count to prevent brute force attacks, is that it is even simpler for an attacker to lockout your users by smashing out N number of attempts for their rainbow list of usernames.  I suppose though, if you want to allow the lesser evil, it would be better that your users get locked out for a while versus your system being infiltrated.

Comment: Could you not lock the client IP rather than the account itself? Granted they could use a VPN or packet switch network but eventually they'll run out of IP addresses to use limiting their brute force & most "free" brute forces don't have the functionality of "remembering" where it stopped in a words list - but again, maybe its worth building but can be turned on or off via the configuration?

Comment: Sure.  These are all good thoughts/considerations.